# Accessing message object instances in Akka Scala

Tags: scala, akka

In Akka's Scala API, how do I get access to the message object that was sent to the actor? Maybe this object is something more complicated than some trivial string, and maybe it contains properties that I want to inspect and use:

```
case class HotSauce(amount : Double, capcaisin : Double)

class SpicyMeatball extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case HotSauce =>
      // How do I get access to the HotSauce message instance?
      val capcaisin = ???.getCapcaisin()
  }
}
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: `HotSauce` is a class name here? Then the `case HotSauce => ...` isn't even valid syntax. If `HotSauce` is a singleton, then I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Yes `HotSauce` is a class, if what you say is true, can you show me what a correct example would look like to obtain the value of the `HotSuace`s, `capcaisin` value *if* a `HotSauce` message was sent to this actor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you define something like a separate little protocol with case classes enumerating the acceptable messages. For example, in your case, it could be something like

```
sealed trait SMP // spicy meatball protocol
case class HotSauce(amount: Double, capcaisin: Double) extends SMP
case class Foobar(baz: String, wambo: Int) extends SMP
```

and then you would structure your `receive` around it:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case HotSauce(n, capcaisin) => /* do something with `n` and `capcaisin` */
  case Foobar(b, w) => /* do sth. with `b` and `w` */
}
```

If your `HotSauce` is *not* a case class, you can still pattern match by type:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case hs: HotSauce => 
    val capcaisin = hs.getCapcaisin()
    // do sth. with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pattern match you can give the matched value a name as `variableName: Type`

example,

```
scala> final case class HotSauce(capcaisin: String)
defined class HotSauce

scala> val data = HotSauce("some value")
data: HotSauce = HotSauce(some value)

scala> data match {
     |   case hotSauce: HotSauce => println(hotSauce.capcaisin)
     |   case _ => println("whatever")
     | }
some value
```

In your example, receive function takes a partial function, and you just provide the matches.

```
type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
```

**So, just give your match a name and you can access the variable, example below**

```
    case h: HotSauce =>
      val capcaisin = h.getCapcaisin()
      //
    }
```

Also, read [How to implement receive () in Akka Actor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22028523/432903)

Answer (score 0):

Case classes have `apply` and `unapply` methods defined. This is the cause that you can use it in pattern matching.

This case is very similar. If you have actor, my propose is to create a companion object to actor which should contain information like: actor name, all messages and other things that are specific for this actor.

Looking at this problem you can use advantages that case classes provides you, so:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case HotSauce(amount, capaisin) =>
    //Here you have access to amount and capaisin
}
```

In that cases you can extract only one or few parameters in case:

```
case HotSauce(_, capaisin) =>
```

or

```
case HotSauce(amount, _) =>
```